# convert python string to nsdictionary

Tags: python, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have a tcp server in Python (using twisted) and many clients, one of which is iOS. When the connections is established, my server sends a python dictionary converted to string to the clients:

```
self.stringRep = str(self.myDictionary)
//somewhere else
self.connection.write(self.stringRep)
```

My question is how do I convert this string representation of python dictionary to NSDictionary in objective-C client. I represent it as NSString in objective-C.

Hope I gave enough details. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: It would be great if this can be done without converting to JSON. If there's no other way, JSON will do.

Comment: I wouldn't use `str()` to make a string representation of a dictionary. Use something like `json.dumps()`, as JSON is a standard format with libraries written in tons of languages.

Comment: What's wrong with JSON?

Comment: I'm a bit inexperienced with JSON. Right now all my client server interactions are via tcp messages where some keywords are separated by a delimiter. I don't know if JSON representation has that or not which may break the interaction. Anyways, even if it works out in best case scenario, refactoring the code for other clients will take time. In future when everything is working, I'll convert to JSON and change my client-server interaction mechanism.

Comment: The JSON representation is almost identical to the Python `str()` representation: `{"a": 2, "c": "\"'", "b": 3}`.

Comment: Yeah just saw it ... maybe it's better to do json after all.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a standard format like `XML` or `JSON`. The later is preferred.

If you need something on the go, consider separating the string into multiple key-value strings and then break each string in the result to what you need.

```
NSString *string = @"{\'a\': \'10\', \'b\': \'20\'}";
NSArray *allEntries = [string componenetsSeparatedByString:@", "];
for(NSString *result in allEntries {
    NSArray *keyValueArray = [result componenetsSeparatedByString:@" : "];
    myDictionary [keyValueArray[0]] = keyValueArray[1];
}
```